# If tag contains numeric value, remove brackets and add class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is a 'View Cart' link on a shopping site where I don't control the HTML:

```
<div class="cart-link">
    <a href="#">
        View Cart <span class="total"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

When items are added to cart, currently the span tag is being updated to contain a space then a number in brackets, like so:

```
View Cart <span class="total"> (1)</span>
```

This is occurring instantly without a page reload (AJAX?).

Not sure if this is possible, but can I use JS/jQuery to 'keep a watch' on that span tag, and as soon as it contains a number, then perform two things: (a) remove the parentheses from around the number, and (2) add an extra class name to the span tag. So it would end up something like this:

```
View Cart <span class="total new-class"> 1</span>
```

Thanks

Comment: If it's AJAX then you can alter the code at the point when the DOM is updated rather than worry about writing new code to "watch" an element.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `MutationObserver`. Observe the `<span>`, and when it changes, check its `textContent` for a number. If it does, perform your desired operations:

```js
const total = document.querySelector('.total');
const observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
  const numMatch = total.textContent.match(/\d+/);
  if (numMatch === null) return;
  changing = true;
  total.textContent = numMatch[0];
  total.classList.add('new-class');
});
observer.observe(total, { childList: true });

setTimeout(() => {
  total.textContent = '(3)';
}, 2000);
```

```css
.new-class {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="cart-link">
    <a href="#">
        View Cart <span class="total"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: that's an awesome feature, i've never heard of it before, thanks.